# Powershell - set desktop background for specific user (Windows 7 and/or 2008 Server)

Tags: windows, powershell, desktop

Assuming I am logged on as administrator, can I use PowerShell to assign a desktop background image to a specific user account?

I've seen answers similar to this one
[Powershell script from shortcut to change desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440135/powershell-script-from-shortcut-to-change-desktop)
where the following is used

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", true);
```

Which, I assume, will work for the currently logged on user. How would I do that for the user that is not logged on (any user)?

The user did not have a desktop background set before.

Any other automated solution welcome, not limited to PowerShell.

Comment: Looks like I could do this by assigning a logon script to the user ... but ideally that would be a once-off script, not to be run each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general consensus seems to be that you need to load the user's registry hive.  I think this is what you're looking for: http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/powershell-loading-and-unloading-registry-hives/