# Get / Change windows background wallpapers or the directory containing these wallpapers

Tags: java, c#, cmd

I have created a program to add climate information in the wallpapers set for background.
To achieve this I was asking user to give the location of directory containing the images that are set for wallpaper in windows.
I am needed to make this task automated. On internet I only found this

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d E:\photos\image1.bmp /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

This is a command line method to change the background image of windows. But by any way it will not help me. I want to change the location of whole directory or a set of images.

**If not clear :** when we set wallpapers for windows we choose the images that we want in background. I want to do all this with programming or command line. And for my program I was also needed to get the location of directory containing images at the current time, so that I can create a copy of these images and then after processing images put new images in the new directory that I set for background so that user may not lose his original images.

**Note :**

1. May be I still not clearly explained my problem. Please let me know if it is so.
2. If it could be achieved by using C#, Java, or with cmd It will help me. But my priority is java, because the program was written completely in java.
3. On internet I also found the C# program to change background images in the same way as I shown above, but as I said, this is not much helpful me.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22344255/2861476) could help

Comment: If somehow I will create C program to do this then I will have my own command line tool to change background image quickly, but still second half of my question is not achieved yet. Thank you for your link, it is very helpful.