# Using batch file to change background

Tags: batch-file, background, wallpaper

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d wallpaper.bmp
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /f /t REG_SZ /d 10
timeout /t 2 /nobreak
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 
start audio.mp3
pause
```

I tried to change my background using a .bat file, and I created this code but it doesn't work, what did I do wrong? (this is my first time using batch files)

The `wallpaper.bmp` and `audio.mp3` files are in the same path as the batch file.

Comment: @lin Please learn how to [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) correctly.

Comment: Well, the audio.mp3 problem will be solved easily. Replace `start audio.mp3` with `start "" audio.mp3`.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22344255/2861476) could help

Comment: Refer to the files with `%~dp0` prefixed to point to the container of the batch script...

Comment: thanks aschipsfl that worked :D