# Change wallpaper powershell

Tags: powershell

Hello i'm trying to make a little script to change my wallpaper every given time 
i have a folder in which the pictures are name 1.bmp , 2.bmp etc

i made this script but it doesn't work at all

```
PS D:\Téléchargements\images\Wallpapers> for($i=1; $i -le 6; $i++){
>> reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ 
/d D:\Téléchargements\images\Wallpapers\$i.bmp /f
>> Start-Sleep -s 10
>> rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
>> Start-Sleep -s 2
>> }
```

can someone explain why please :(

PS : the start-sleep values are totally random and here for testing

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, what are they? If not, what do you see happening (or not happening)? If you wish assistance in troubleshooting a script, you need to provide as much information as possible. Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, you may find [this page from The Agreeable Cow](http://www.theagreeablecow.com/2014/09/set-desktop-wallpaper-using-powershell.html) of interest.

Comment: i'm not having any errors messages, only "Operation succeeded" every 10 secondes but my wallpaper is not changing

Comment: After the script succeeds, please go into REGEDIT and report the value of the attribute `Wallpaper` when you look at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`

Comment: well it says 3.bmp but the desktop is still the first image, i executed again rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUsertSystemParameters

but nothing changed at all still the first image while the registery key says 3.bmp

Comment: Try deleting the space after the comma in `rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell script from shortcut to change desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440135/powershell-script-from-shortcut-to-change-desktop)

Answer (score 11):

This should fix the problem(checked in win 10):

```
 reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d h:\Quotefancy-1542-3840x2160.jpg /f
 Start-Sleep -s 10
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters, 0, $false
```

or you can use win32 api like this:

```
$setwallpapersrc = @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class wallpaper
{
 public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
 public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
 public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
 public static void SetWallpaper ( string path )
 {
  SystemParametersInfo( SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange );
 }
}"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $setwallpapersrc

[wallpaper]::SetWallpaper("h:\Quotefancy-1542-3840x2160.jpg")
```

Comment: I've used the win32 API solution as part of a script, but it only seems to work if I run the code in a PowerShell terminal manually. If I schedule it as a task, the script runs and exits 0, and does the other stuff in the script (namely downloading and cropping a new wallpaper), but the wallpaper doesn't change. Not sure why :(

Comment: @rensa are you running the script as the logged on user? when I run it with the setting "Run whether user is logged on or not" it doesn't work for me.

Comment: That's expected since "Run whether user is logged on or not" will run the script using a mechanism similar to "secondary logon" (runas) so cannot interact with the current logged on session. That's by design.

Comment: The win32 api part works perfectly when pasted into a powershell terminal. Thank you!

Comment: This did not work at all on WIn10 powershell.